# Frame of viewForHeaderInSection is always the same size

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grouped-table

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

 if(section != 0) {

  UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)] autorelease];
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  return view;

 } else {
  return tableView.tableHeaderView;
 }
```

}

This is my implementation of viewForHeaderInSection but whatever frame I make it's always showing me the same red frame. Do you see any problem with my code?

Image:

[image]

UPDATE:

Mhm now my red block is higher but my first tableHeader is now somehow hidden. The first one was implemented with the titleForHeaderInSection. I thought I just implement the height of the tableHeader height but that doesnt work

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(section == 1)
    return 30;
else
    return tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to implement this delegate method

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

In your case, you can simply `return 30;`.

---

Also, **you are leaking `view`!**

Your `[view release]` happens after the `return`.  But as soon as the `return` happens the method execution is aborted and your `release` is never called.

So you want this instead

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)] autorelease];
```

And get rid of the explicit `release` down below.

Comment: thx, you know why they dom't take rame height? dont see why I have to set the height in a extra delegate method...

Comment: I don't know why Apple did it this way.  It's a little silly.   But I think they intended the header frame to *always* span the entire width of the table view.  So the only size variable left to mess with is the height.

Comment: thx about the hint of the autorelease. But now I have another problem, maybe you can help me another time?

Comment: This is a different issue and it's a little unclear.  Post a new question with only the relevant code and a new image showing the problem.

Comment: thx a lot. Did that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450957/height-of-tableheaderview-seems-to-be-0