# Height of tableHeaderView seems to be 0

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grouped-table

I tried to override the second tableHeaderView. But it seems that the height of it in the method  heightForHeaderInSection seems to be 0. Can't explain it, do I have to put it in a iVar because in the viewForHeaderInSection I can set the view without any problems.

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(section == 0)
    return @"Adding a new list";
else
    return @"Other lists";

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0) {
    return tableView.tableHeaderView;
} else {
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return view;
}

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(section == 0)
    return tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height;
else
    return 30;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing the table header and the header for each section, they are different.  There is no "second tableHeaderView", a `UITableView` has one `tableHeaderView` and then depends on the `viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` methods to place custom header views for each section, otherwise you just use `titleForHeaderInSection` to place text there.

Comment: ok, but my approach is to have different section headers. 
First one should use the text and the second should use the text + an uibutton.

Comment: I'm not sure you can mix titleForHeaderInSection and viewForHeaderInSection, you must create custom views for each section if you want to use viewForHeaderInSection at all.

Comment: You can call `titleForHeaderInSection` from your own custom `viewForHeaderInSection`.  So you can still use it to manage your titles.  But there is no magic here and you have to stitch the 2 methods together yourself.  It wont ask for a title if the delegate is setup to provide header views.